# How do I repeat row labels in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi

I have data showing me the dates grouped like this:

[image: Current Result]

For security reasons, I had to remove the `Customer Description` detail, due to confidentiality.

How do I repeat the date column the same way you repeat the Row Labels in an Excel Pivot?

I've looked, but couldn't find a solution to this - this option should be available.

**EDIT**

When you have the following source data in Excel:

```
Date        |   Customer    |   Item Description    |    Qty Out    |    Unit Price     |    Sales 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14/08/2020  |   Customer 1  |   Item 11         |    4.00       |    65.00      |    260.00 
14/08/2020  |   Customer 2  |   Item 12         |    56.00      |    12.00      |    672.00 
14/08/2020  |   Customer 3  |   Item 13         |    64.00      |    35.00      |    2,240.00 
14/08/2020  |   Customer 4  |   Item 14         |    29.00      |    65.00      |    1,885.00 
15/08/2020  |   Customer 2  |   Item 15         |    746.00     |    12.00      |    8,952.00 
15/08/2020  |   Customer 3  |   Item 16         |    14.00      |    75.00      |    1,050.00 
15/08/2020  |   Customer 4  |   Item 17         |    45.00      |    741.00     |    33,345.00 
15/08/2020  |   Customer 5  |   Item 18         |    456.00     |    125.00     |    57,000.00 
15/08/2020  |   Customer 6  |   Item 19         |    925.00     |    17.00      |    15,725.00 
16/08/2020  |   Customer 4  |   Item 20         |    6.00       |    532.00     |    3,192.00 
16/08/2020  |   Customer 5  |   Item 21         |    56.00      |    94.00      |    5,264.00 
16/08/2020  |   Customer 6  |   Item 22         |    546.00     |    37.00      |    20,202.00
```

You then pivot this data using Microsoft Excel, where you get the following:

[image: Current Results]

You then choose the option to Repeat Item Labels as can be seen below:

[image: Repeating Item Labels]

After selecting this, you get my expected results I require in Power BI:

[image: Expected Results]

Is there not a function available like this in Power BI?

Comment: As you said you have value in other column as well, can you show you minimum set of sample data that shows all scenario? Often we can not find solution, because of incomplete explanation of the requirement.

Comment: @mkRabbani, I've added more detail to my edit to show you the reason why I require a matrix... :)

Comment: Hi Birel, I have posted 2 possible option for your. Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding this for your reference as a work around. Check this below image with a custom column created in the **Power Query Editor**-

```
date_customer = Date.ToText([Date]) &" : "& [Customer]
```

Then added both **Date** and **date_customer** in the Matrix row level. The output is as below- **(using your sample data)**

[image]

**ANOTHER OPTION** Another option is to add **Date** and **Customer** in the Matrix row and the output is will be as below- **(using your sample data)**

[image]

This is also a meaningful output as date are showing as a group header. But in case of requirement of having redundant date to show, you can consider the first option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mkRabbani, however this is not the case. My data in Power Query is showing the dates for every row, but when I add the date column to my matrix, I have a few transactions from different customers for the same date - which Power BI groups and does not show the date for each row - which is what I need. When you pivot data in Excel, you have the option to choose `Repeat Item Labels` in Excel - I'm looking for the same function in Power BI...

Comment: HI @Birel, can you tell me the column name you are using in Matrix - Rows, Columns and Values? The nature of matrix is Grouping values from rows and then create columns dynamically from the distinct list of value from the given column. And then show value. This is expected.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, thank you for your assistance so far, please have a look at the edit I made to my question. :)

Comment: Matrix has three properties- Rows, Columns and Values. Can you let us know how you are mapping those with table column? Btw, your last image is a simple Table visual output in Power BI. Not sure why you wants Matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mkRabbani, I require to use a matrix, because I have values in separate columns as well, with their relevant values - the same results cannot be obtained using only a table.

Comment: But, as per my last 2 days analysis - you can not achieve your required output as well using Matrix. My bad if I missed the option during my analysis.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @mkRabbani. Just disappointed that Power BI does not have this function yet as some clients require to see it like this...